# Preferred method of T-SQL if condition to improve query plan re-use

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-execution-plan

I want to understand which is the better method of implementing a "IF" condition inside a stored procedure.

I have seen this method used extensively. Which is comparable to iterative coding...

```
declare @boolExpression bit = 1 --True

if @boolExpression  = 1
  select column from MyTable where group = 10
else
  select column from MyTable where group = 20
```

I prefer to use a set based method...

```
declare @boolExpression bit = 1 --True

select column from MyTable where group = 10 and @boolExpression  =1
union all
select column from MYTable where group = 20 and @boolExpression =0
```

I prefer to use this method because as I understand it creates a re-useable query plan and less plan cache churn. Is this fact or fiction? Which is the correct method to use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you missing a `UNION ALL` in the second one?

Comment: Yes, thanks Martin, UNION ALL is missing. I'll add it in

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are missing a `UNION ALL` There isn't much in it as far as I can see. The first version will cache a plan for each statement as children of a `COND` operator such that only the relevant one will get invoked at execution time.

[image: Plan 1 screenshot]

The second one will have both branches as children of a concatenation operator. The filters have a Startup Expression Predicate meaning that each seek is only evaluated if required.

[image: Plan 2 screenshot]

Comment: the bit parameter has either 1 or 0 values so why union when one of the select statements will always return 0 rows?

Comment: @Adrian - So only one result set is returned. Instead of returning 2 result sets - One empty and one containing data.

Comment: The question was really about query plan re-use. My example included the most basic query to illustrate my request. In reality much more complex queries will be in question.

Comment: @sqlconsumer.net - Well it doesn't make any difference for the case in your question and you haven't explained how your real situation differs from your stated situation.

Comment: So will this method allow the stored procedure query plan to be more re-usable?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use it as follows:

```
DECLARE @boolExpression BIT = 1

SELECT column FROM MyTable 
WHERE 
    CASE 
        WHEN @boolExpression = 1 THEN 
            CASE 
                WHEN group = 10 THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
            END 
        ELSE 
            CASE 
                WHEN group = 20 THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
            END 
    END = 1
```

I know that it looks complicated but does the trick, especially in-cases when the applying of a parameter in a stored procedure is optional.

Comment: This is unsargable and will give a scan not a seek.

Comment: @Martin Smith: Thank you for your comment, I agree that it's gonna be a scan. Just wanted to depict another way for conditional operation in the WHERE clause, because it's more easy to maintain for changes, until and unless performance becomes a real concern, which would be subject-to-change w.r.t actual-need/requirement; which wasn't really clear in the question.